# Wrong output with SQL

Tags: sql, select

I am using the following Query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Lecturer.Name, Course.CourseId
FROM Lecturer JOIN Lecture ON Lecturer.LecturerId = Lecture.LecturerId
JOIN   Course ON Lecture.CourseId = Course.CourseId 
     JOIN   (SELECT Course.CourseId 
    FROM Course
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM Exam 
            WHERE  Exam.CourseId = Course.CourseId
            AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM Exam
                      WHERE Grade >= 6)
            <
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Exam
            WHERE Grade < 6)))
```

Only the problem is that it gives the wrong output...

Comment: This sure is a Homework question :)

Comment: It would help us answer your question if you define what exactly is wrong with your output, what you would expect, what you actually get.

Comment: @Saju homework or not has no relevance to the question. the main thing here is that the question will be closed because it's not clear what the user wants and we're not here to make assumptions

Comment: @user2158447 - what is the criteria for passing the course? `Exam.grade > <what>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The query below is not fully tested since there are no sample data provided.*

```
SELECT  d.LecturerID, d.Name,
        c.CourseID, c.CourseName,
        a.Semester,
        a.percentageOfStudent
FROM
        (
            SELECT  CourseID,
                    Semester,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN grade >= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) * 100.0 percentageOfStudent
            FROM    Exam
            GROUP   BY CourseID, Semester
            HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN grade >= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) * 100.0 < 50
        ) a 
        INNER JOIN Lecture b
            ON  a.CourseID = b.CourseID AND
                a.Semester = b.Semester
        INNER JOIN Course c
            ON  b.CourseID = c.CourseID
        INNER JOIN  Lecturer d
            ON b.LecturerID = d.LecturerID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it says : Query Error: no such column: c.Semester Unable to execute statement

Comment: try it again, the reason why error was thrown is I join `Lecture` and `Course` by semester.

Comment: if you need more clarification, just ask `:)`

Comment: Dear J W @J W, could you please help me with 2 other problems i have? That would be great! Thanks in advance! here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006017/problems-with-writing-sql-stored-procedure-trigger